# qt: No rule to make target '/mainwindow.ui', needed by 'ui_mainwindow.h'.?

Tags: qt

No rule to make target '/mainwindow.ui', needed by 'ui_mainwindow.h'. Stop.  file not found

I am using this project: https://github.com/doc-sparks/Interface/tree/v0.1

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a build clean, and run qmake again, and make sure there aren't any ui files or references to a ui file in your code.

Looking through your github repo, it didn't look like there was one, but maybe in your branch there is.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had an earlier error and forgot I modified the ".pro" file.  I also needed "QT += opengl" for the original problem... thx